# Bigquery - Calculate Quantity Added to Cart

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Is there a way to calculate Quantity Added to Cart similar to the GA metric:

**ga:quantityAddedToCart**

- UI Name: Quantity Added To Cart
- Number of product units added to the shopping cart (Enhanced Ecommerce).

In the [BQ Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en), I only see these three things:

- **hits.product.productQuantity**  INTEGER: The quantity of the product purchased.
- **hits.item.itemQuantity**    INTEGER: The quantity of the product sold.
- **hits.eCommerceAction.action_type**  STRING: The action type. Click through of product lists = 1, Product detail views = 2, Add product(s) to cart = 3, Remove product(s) from cart = 4, Check out = 5, Completed purchase = 6, Refund of purchase = 7, Checkout options = 8, Unknown = 0.

The first two only talk about the quantity **sold** and I already tried to see if I could combine these two with hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = 3, but no luck as per below:

```
SELECT
  date,
  product.v2ProductName AS productListName,
  CASE WHEN hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '3' THEN item.itemQuantity ELSE 0 
  END AS quantityAddedToCart_method1,
  CASE WHEN hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '3' THEN product.productQuantity ELSE 0 
  END AS quantityAddedToCart_method2
FROM
  `{PROJECT_ID}.{VIEW_ID}.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product) product
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190401' AND '20190430'
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and where the problem was? or you are just looking for plain answer?

Comment: I have tried as per above. Yes, I'm looking for an answer to confirm or deny if this is even possible with the BigQuery data. The problem is the numbers do not match up with the values for ga:quantityAddedToCart as seen in GA.